# Alternative to ibus typing booster Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-recommendation, ibus

Is there any alternative to Ibus typing booster for Ubuntu 18.04. I am not able to install ibus typing booster in Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried the solutions provided in askubuntu forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ibus-typing-booster` is available in the official repositories since Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately, it [is not available as .deb package for releases of Debian or Ubuntu prior to 20.04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/is-ibus-typing-booster-available-in-ubuntu-20-04/15303/3).

That means you will need to compile it yourself. Here are some brief instructions ([source](https://www.2daygeek.com/install-ibus-typing-booster-improve-speedup-your-typing-speed-in-arch-linx-fedora-debian-ubuntu-centos-opensuse/)):

```
sudo apt-get install ibus libibus-1.0-dev
git clone git://github.com/mike-fabian/ibus-typing-booster.git
cd ibus-typing-booster
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib/ibus
make
sudo make install
```

The official manual is available [here](https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/development.html).